# How can I send sms with text by using phonegap on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am trying to send sms on iphone.
But it works with only sms number well, but it doesn't work with sms number and text.

In other words, following works well.

> `<a href="sms:+05212341234">Send sms</a>`

But it doesn't work.

> `<a href="sms:+05212341234?body=hello">Send sms</a>`

I am using phonegap now, if you know its reason, please help me.
Cheers.

Comment: this will not work as the URL scheme for sms is not allowed with body query parameter.

Comment: @Futur That doesn't seem right to me. The RFC for the SMS protocol clearly shows that body is an acceptable parameter. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5724

Comment: Yes it is mentioned, you are right. Let me dig thru this and find out why it isn't implemented. Thanks for the insight. Got to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SMS composer plugins for phonegap, its working fine for me.

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer
```

Comment: The plugins are no longer on github in a master repo, they can be found here: http://plugins.cordova.io/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this the case but you misspelled "href", you wrote instead "herf"